# Swtich from UiApp to HtmlService

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, web-applications

I'm not a programmer or anything so please excuse any mistake.

I'm trying to use a code in Apps Script to facilitate data entry on a google sheets that I found online. The problem is the original creator used UiApp which has been deprecated.

I've been scouring the internet for anyway of making the change to Html but with no result.
I was hoping one of you could help me out!

Thank you

```
function doGet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1J_Fi7-hJuZkA2UftqM1Q-SG5NWxdQZkhLGjLIlVowTc/edit?usp=sharing'); //the spreadsheets url in which you want to change
  var app = UiApp.createApplication(); //creates the application
  var ss = sheet.getSheets()[0]; //gets the first sheet in the spreadsheet
  var myPanel = app.createVerticalPanel(); //creates a vertical panel
  var scroll = app.createScrollPanel().setPixelSize(200, 600); //creates a scrolling panel with the dimensions in its parameter
  var panel3 = app.createVerticalPanel(); //creates a vertical panel
  var panel4 = app.createVerticalPanel(); //creates a vertical panel
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel(); //creates a vertical panel
  var panel2 = app.createAbsolutePanel().setSize('100%','100%').setId('absPanel'); //creates an absolute panel that covers the whole application
  var periodKey = sheet.getSheetByName('Periods');//gets the sheet titled periods
  var periodKeyValues = periodKey.getDataRange().getValues();//gets the values in the sheet
  var guildKey = sheet.getSheetByName('Guilds');//gets the sheet titled Guilds
  var guildKeyValues = guildKey.getDataRange().getValues();//gets the values in that sheet
```

Comment: I'm afraid you are just going to have to learn how to use HTML to build your page.  Then there is [Templated HTML](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates) to build the page on server side using spreadsheet values before the page is displayed and [Client side API using google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run) to communicated to the server spreadsheet from the client browser.  Your example seems pretty simple, I've I knew what it looked like I could probably help with a simple mock up.

Comment: Please start by learning the pretty basics of developing a web application using "vanilla" HTML/JavaScript/CSS, (Mozilla Developers Network and freecodecamp.com among many others might be helpful) then read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web. If you don't have time or will to learn, consider to use a no-code tool like Google AppSheet (you could create a no code app from Google Sheets, start by adding a data table, then click on Extensions - AppSheet)

Comment: The app is used to add values to a spreadsheet with the students name en masse instead of having to open the spreadsheet everytime i need to add the value. Like it's shown here at minute 30: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8eo0I46qFs&t=1811s

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of how to build a table using HTML Service using a template and then using google.script.run to send new data to the spreadsheet.

My spreadsheet Sheet1 looks like this.
[image]

Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
  try {
    let html = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("HTML_Test");
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1uqq7UeFgYBM_Onzcq0o9ZuHLcmMEotN8hlmo83Ipt0A");
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let data = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues(); // data includes dates
    html.data = data;
    return html.evaluate();
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}

function addRow(values) {
  try {
    let spread = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1..your id here...A");
    let sheet = spread.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
    let row = [ values.id, values.name, values.date ];
    sheet.appendRow(row);
    return row;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
  }
}
```

HTML_Test

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <style>
      table, th, td {
        width: 10%;
        border: 1px solid black;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="inputFields">
      ID:<input id="idField" type="text"><br>
      Name:<input id="nameField" type="text"><br>
      Date:<input id="dateField" type="text"><br>
      <input id="submitButton" type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitOnClick()">
    </div>
    <div id="tableDiv">
      <table id="myTable">
        <? for( var i=0; i<data.length; i++ ) { ?>
          <tr>
            <? for( var j=0; j<data[0].length; j++ ) { ?>
              <td>
                <?= data[i][j] ?>
              </td>
            <? } ?>
          </tr>
        <? } ?>
      </table>
    </div>
    <script>
      function submitOnClick() {
        try {
          let id = document.getElementById("idField").value;
          let name = document.getElementById("nameField").value;
          let date = document.getElementById("dateField").value;
          // make sure its a valid date
          if( isNaN(Date.parse(date)) ) throw "invalid date";
          google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(
            function(values) {
              let table = document.getElementById("myTable");
              let row = table.insertRow(-1);
              for( let i=0; i<values.length; i++ ) {
                let cell = row.insertCell(i);
                cell.innerHTML = values[i];
              }
            }
          ).addRow({ id: id, name: name, date: date });
        }
        catch(err) {
          alert(err);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

My form looks like this

[image]

References:

- [HTML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/)
- [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)
- [Javascript and HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/default.asp)